# How to style my desirable nav-tabs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this>
  [my desired look for nav tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjVXX.jpg)

But I ended up achieving this[the look I managed to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1GBy.jpg)

code I used : (I am using bootstrap and these are just on topic partial codes)
customstyles.css>

```css
.nav li a {
background-color: #e2b12e;
border-right: 1px solid #674d03;
color: #674d03;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
height: 59px;
line-height: 18px;
padding: 21px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: 1px;
}
```

Index.html>

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ul_content ">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                <li>
                    <a href="#dashboardTab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>MyAccount</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#studentsTab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>Students</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#teachersTab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lamp"></span>Teachers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Examination</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>Attendance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Timetable</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>Fees</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Settings</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            <!--<div class="tab-content">
            <div id="dashboardTab" class="tab-pane">
                <h3>Dashboard Page</h3>
                <p>Dashboard Page Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>-->



        </div>


    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 ul_content">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span>Hostel</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span>Transport</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>Library</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Downloads</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span>Import</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>Export</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Notify</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Purchase</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>HR</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

please tell what I did wrong and what I should change to achieve my desired look for those nav tabs.

Comment: Can you put it all in the code snipet? You can add bootstrap by adding the cdn links from bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ u see the 4 links in here)

Comment: No problems with bootstrap Jeremy. I have provided full code for customstyles.css . I have not used any other css codes.

Comment: Your snippet is broken, please make a fully working example that properly shows us the problem you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

**1 -** You're missing the `<div class="container"></div>` tags wrapping your code. That's why no one is getting the correct output. Also add HTML and CSS in the code snippet.

**2 -** It's bad that you are using `<ul> <li>` to achieve what you want. When working with bootstrap just wrap your elements with `<div>` and work with the classes. You could be inheriting stuff from these other tags, it's good to have full control over your elements, so using `<div>` and `<span>` is the way to go.

**3 -** After apllying these changes I would do something like this:

```css
.each_tab a {
background-color: #e2b12e;
border-right: 1px solid #674d03;
color: #674d03;
display: block;
font-size: 11px;
height: 59px;
line-height: 18px;
padding: 21px 0px 0px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: 1px;
}

.nav {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.each_tab {
    display: table-cell;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ul_content ">
            <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#dashboardTab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span>Dashboard</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                    MyAccount
                    </a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab active">
                    <a href="#studentsTab" data-toggle="tab">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education"></span>Students</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#teachersTab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lamp"></span>Teachers</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>Courses</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Examination</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>Attendance</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>Timetable</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>Fees</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Settings</a>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ul_content">
        <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span>Hostel</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span>Transport</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>Library</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Downloads</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span>Import</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>Export</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>Notify</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></span>Reports</a>
            </div>
            
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Purchase</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="each_tab">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>HR</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Raphael S. Rodrigues for helping me. It looks great now. I have made only one change .each_tab {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 60px;
}      I have upvoted your answer but my reputation is below 15...so, it's not showing.